# Compute $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\, dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\, dz $$ where $\gamma(t)=e^{-it}, t\in \,[0,8\pi].$

I've done this the following way: $$\int_0^{8\pi}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\, dt=\int_{0}^{8\pi}e^{it}\cdot-ie^{-it}\, dt=\int_0^{8\pi}-i \, dt=-8\pi i$$

I was happy with this but then I tried doing the calculation using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and found the answer to be $0$. Which one is correct? And why is there a difference?

Comment: You can't apply FTC because $1/z$ has no primitive which would be continuous and defined along the whole curve $\gamma$.

Comment: The FTC doesn't apply because $\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't have a primitive defined on (a neighbourhood of) the [trace of the] path $\gamma$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why is $\operatorname{ln}z$ not defined on this path?

Comment: @user332597 You can define $\ln z$ along this path, by choosing where to put its branch cut, but you can't make $\ln z$ continuous on the whole path.

Comment: The complex logarithm is multiplayered, and for each time you go around the origin once, you go one layer up or down. The "distance" between the layers is $2\pi i$, so for each revolution that $\gamma$ makes around the origin (counterclockwise), another $2\pi i$ gets added to the integral of $\frac1z$. Your path goes four times around clockwise, so that makes it $-8\pi i$.