# What closed paths make $\int_{\gamma} \frac 1 z dz = 2m \pi i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 4.14

[This text](https://maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/414/414-ch1.pdf) talks about [winding numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) in Def 1.17. In the textbook, I think Exer 4.13 refers to winding numbers.

> [image]

1. Does Exer 4.13 refer to winding numbers, and is the $m$ in Exer 4.14 a winding number of $\gamma$?
2. Can I choose [unit circle but keep it winding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031753) $m-1$ more times, i.e. $\gamma(t) = e^{it}, t \in [0,2 m\pi]$? I mean it doesn't say simple $\gamma$.
3. Actually, how about $\gamma=\gamma_1\gamma_2 \cdots \gamma_m$ where $\gamma_2, \dots, \gamma_m$ are copies of a closed simple path $\gamma_1$ s.t. $0 \in int(\gamma_1)$?

Comment: Yes. Yes, as long as $m$ is positive: what if $m\le0$?

Comment: Nice try, @LordSharktheUnknown. $m>0$ and in fact $m \in \mathbb Z$ because otherwise $\gamma=\gamma_1\gamma_2 \cdots \gamma_m$ wouldn't make sense :P (I guess?) Thanks!

Comment: @AnginaSeng why the username change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4.13, for $n = -1$ you have the winding number of $\gamma$ about the origin.  An immediate reason the others are zero is that for $n \not= -1$, 
$z^n$ is a derivative.

For your second question, the answer is yes.

For your third question, the answer is __ BCLC: yes I guess? ___.

Comment: Edit: I split up 2 into 2 and 3. Any changes please? Thanks ncmathsadist!

Comment: 3 works as well.

Comment: ncmathsadist, wait edited 3. I think I have to let 0∈int(γ1). Now 3 is right but previously 3 was wrong?